# How to override models __str__ method so you would have different presentation in admin panel

Tags: django

What is the clean way to override `__str__` method of a model so that admin and super admin see it differently in admin panel.

In my model class I want to check if user is `is_superuser` or not so I could show different things in `__str__` method.

Point of this is the situation that my `super admin` can see all objects belonging to everyone but `normal admin` can only see his objects so if I write:

> `def __str__(self):`
>
> ```
>    return "Object: %s , created by: %s"%(self.title,self.created_by)
> ```

My super admin will be able to see who is the creator of object in panel, and that is fine.
But my normal admin will see only his objects and not needed message saying that he is the creator.
That is why I would need a different return in `__str__` method for normal admins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing it in `__str__` method, you can specify which fields to display in the list in admin.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return ('title' , 'created_by')
        else:
            return ('title',)
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

and then update your `__str__` method to return just the title.